# How to set foreign key constraint name in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

When I annotate a object inside my entity class as following

```
@ManyToOne
private User creator;
```

`SchemaExport` ends up creating "creator_id" in the entity table. (Which is good). But

```
 alter table Voucher 
        add constraint FK2DF5CE507B0A07EF 
        foreign key (creator_id) 
        references User;
```

the constraint name is randomly generated string. Which changers. Is there any annotation where I can set this constraint name ? (if there is such way I would like to know both annotation and hbm.xml configuration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [@ForeignKey](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey.html) annotation.

Comment: thank you. I was searching for parameters inside JoinColumn, ManyToOne and everywhere.

Comment: Generating the database schema from the entities is not part of the JPA specification. This is a proprietary add-on of Hibernate. That's why there's no standard JPA annotation to do that.